# Assembly.Load x86/x64/AnyCPU

Tags: c#, .net, build, cpu-architecture

I am designing a client application that will list several applications that I offer. A user will pick the application, and press run, then the application will be downloaded and will be loaded into the client application's domain using Assembly.Load. Here's the snippet of where it gets loaded:

```
        var vAsm = Assembly.Load(client.GetBase());
        var vEP = vAsm.EntryPoint;
        var vSC = vAsm.GetType(vEP.DeclaringType.FullName).GetMethod("SetClient");
        var vInst = vAsm.CreateInstance(vEP.Name);
        vSC.Invoke(vInst, new object[] { client, license }); 
        vEP.Invoke(vInst, null);
```

Problem: Two of the current applications are 32bit. However one of my applications is 64bit.

Question: If I build the client application in AnyCPU, will it be able to load both the 32bit applications AND the 64bit application? Or is there maybe a setting that launches it in 64bit if the machine supports it? This would be ideal, as I would just detect if they are 32bit/64bit and warn them that the one application is not supported on their machine if that's the case.

I will be testing this myself, but maybe somebody could give me some sort of advice to handle this.

Thanks!

Comment: Please put the code `with formatting` into your question.  This allows everyone to see, and easily edit your existing code for you, and makes the questions/answers much more readable.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your first question, if you compile the application as AnyCPU you let Windows decide which CLR to pick.  In my experience, it usually works out to Windows picking the x64 CLR on x64 operating systems and the x86 CLR on x86 operating systems but I'm not certain if that's always a guarantee.  AnyCPU does not mean that it gets to run in both.  You will only be able to load the version of the application which corresponds to the architecture of the CLR which loaded your client application.

I've had to deal with this sort of thing in some of the applications that I work with at the place where I'm working.  I've run into some frustrating bugs when I tried interoperating with applications compiled for a specific architecture and applications compiled for AnyCPU.  To make things easier and more predictable, I just ended up compiling the "AnyCPU" applications which had to interact with the "non AnyCPU" applications for each architecture for which they had to interact.  There may be some people who have a more sophisticated setup but it wasn't worth the headache for me.

So, the answer to the second question is more advice.  I'd just compile the client application for a specific architecture so that you know for sure which architecture that you're dealing with and then add appropriate code to detect the architecture.  In fact, I think that you could use some compiler directives to store some sort of indicator as to which architecture that you're running under or even put a "detection" branch specific to each architecture in the compiler directive and that would help you do the warning that you're thinking of doing.

The alternative is to keep the client application as AnyCPU and detect which architecture the application is currently running under (if memory serves, it's IntPtr.Size == 8 for x64 applications but there may be more reliable methods; not sure...) and then only launch the appropriate applications.  But still, you have to be mindful of the fact that, even with AnyCPU, you can only load applications of the specific architecture of the CLR which is running your AnyCPU client application.

Does that make sense?

Comment: Yep! That does make sense.And I will definitely be doing checks for architecture before allowing them to run the 64bit application as well. So in the end I do have to do some experimenting. And I could always release a 32bit and a 64bit client like some people do.

Comment: Glad it makes sense.  Experimenting will be good.  There are a few different ways of getting this done and you've got to figure out the way that works best for you.  :)

Answer (score 0):

You should build all your binaries in AnyCPU. That way, on a 64-bit OS, they'll run as 64-bit and on a 32-bit OS, they'll run as 32-bit. If you compile to x64, it won't run on a 32-bit OS at all. If you compile to x86, you'll always run as 32-bit, even on a 64-bit OS. The final rule is that you can't mix & match x86 and x64 bins in the same process. The mismatching ones will fail to load.